# How to install Hive For Windows?

Tags: hadoop, hive, installation

I have installed hadoop. I used hadoop-2.7.0-src.tar.gz and hadoop-2.7.0.tar.gz files. And uses apache-maven-3.1.1 to collect the hadoop tar file for windows.
After so many tries I made it run. It was difficult to install hadoop without knowing what I am doing.

Now I want to install Hive. Do I have to  collect Hive files with Maven?
If yes what folders should I use to collect them?
And then I want to install sqoop.
Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried on windows but I did on Linux - Ubuntu, and I have detailed these step by step in my blog over here - [Hive Install](https://my-bigdata-blog.blogspot.in/search/label/PIG%20%26%20HIVE)
Have a look, I think most of the steps will be necessary in the same sequence as described but nature of command may be different for windows.

Comment: How can I "Initialize metastore schema" on  windows shell? @Kamal

Comment: the question mentioned windows not Linux